# How to retrive all types of data from sqlserver in datagridview on button click?

Tags: c#, sql

I want to know how I can retrieve image's from sqlserver in DataGridView on a button click. I can show other types of data with the following code and at image column it is showing error. So how can I show all types of data column-wise in DataGridView on button click including image in c#.

```
private void ViewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-FQBMN3R\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentDB; Integrated Security=true");
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter("select *  from tbl_student_info", connection);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sd.Fill(ds, "tbl_student_info");
    ViewDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: What SQL Server datatype is your image column?  If it's the actual `image` datatype, it's a variable-length binary value and you need to translate it into something a `DataGridView` can display.   In other news, that datatype is being deprecated and [Microsoft advises you quit using it](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(v=sql.105).aspx), though since you're a student you may not have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL datatype `image` is returned as a `byte[]` in c#. To turn this into an actual image you'd do something like this:

```
var imgArray = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FILE_IMAGE"];
using (var s = new MemoryStream(imgArray))
{
    var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(s);
}
```

Comment: this is not working ..it is showing "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in StudentManagementSystem.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'."

Comment: Hi Skynova, seems like you need to check for null (i.e. no image)